# Unsteady flow equation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, flow

[image]

I am having trouble understanding how the unsteady flow equation is formulated. Why does it say that the RHS of the equation(change of energy in system) is made up of internal energy, kinetic energy and potential energy? Where is the flow energy? Shouldn't enthalpy $(u+pv)$ be considered? Note i am talking about the RHS of equation specifically. I understand how the energy components from mass in/out comes about. I noticed some people mentioned that the flow work is 0 in the system as there is no boundary work on the system but pressure can change in unsteady flow which means that change in flow work $(pv)$ should be accounted for right? Where am i going wrong with my concept. I hope i am not blabbering too much and being too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should only be u in the RHS, and not h.  The reason h is used on the LHS is that the total work is subdivided into two parts:  1.  The shaft work and 2. The work to push fluid into and out of the control volume.  The latter, in the form of $\dot{m}Pv$ is then lumped in with the u to give rise to $\dot{m}(u+Pv)=\dot{m}h$.  So the $\dot{W}$ in the equation is only the shaft work.

Comment: why should there be only u on rhs? Why not h? When we balance lhs =rhs we should consider work to push fluid in and out of control volume as the fluid in the control volume is technically also flowing in order for fluid to move in and out.

Comment: To know the answers to your questions, you need to re-familiarize yourself with the derivation  of the open-system (control-volume) version of the 1 st law of thermodynamics.  I don't think I can explain it better than the derivations given in all the text books.  I tried here to focus on the reasons, but obviously was not able to do it in a way that resonated with you.

Comment: after looking through some textbooks, i finally got it. Basically i got confused by the idea of bernoulli's equation with the pressure term. People(my prof) calls it pressure energy so i thought that it is one aspect of the energy of a system just like kinetic energy, potential energy and internal energy. In fact, the term is simply work done which needs to be accounted in the system as you are adding new energy. This can be grouped together with W or work done term in the open flow derivation, which therefore means that it will not be included in the RHS naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the generic depiction of an open system shown below, that I have used teaching the subject, will help you understand how the steady flow first law equation is developed. All the terms are defined below the figure. For unsteady flow, $\dot m_{i} \ne \dot m_e$.

For specific cases (ideal turbines, compressors, and heat exchangers) various terms drop out. In most cases the changes in kinetic and gravitational potential energy terms are ignored. Then for heat exchangers (e.g., condensers and evaporators) the work term is zero. Finally, for ideal turbines and compressors, the heat terms are zero. Usually you will be dealing with changes in enthalpy at the input and output of the device of interest.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: what i would like to know is more related to an unsteady flow. The dE/dt term. Why does it not contain the flow energy term?

Comment: The dE/dt term is the difference between the energy flow rate in an energy flow rate out and that, in turn, is determined by the difference between $\dot m_e$ and $\dot m_i$

Comment: so enthalpy is actually required to be accounted for but in many cases, we can simplify it to simply internal energy as the flow work+ke+pe are negligible in comparison to the internal energy?

Comment: @Shane whether or not you can ignore the $pv$ term in $h$ and use only $u$ depends on the particular situation and how much accuracy you want. As an example, for saturated water vapor (as possibly  the output of an evaporator) at 1 atm (101.35 kPa) from the steam tables we get a specific volume of 1.6729 m^${3}$/kg, $u=2506$ kJ/kg and $h=2676$ kJ/kg for a difference between $u$ and $h$ of about 170 kJ/kg, which equals t$u$ plus he $pv$ term (101.35 x 1.6729),  for an about 6% error. If that’s an acceptable accuracy, I suppose you could ignore the $pv$ term.

Comment: The RHS E should only have u, and not h, irrespective of what pv is.